# Как поместить Object.children в переменную, а не ссылку на список?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая превращает текст в html объект:

```
var createNodesByHTML = (function(){
    var div = d.createElement("div");
    return function ( html ) {
        div.innerHTML = html;
        return div.children;
    };
})();
```

Прошу заметить что она возвращает не один эле мент а набор.

Эта функция используется для присвоения классу свойства:

```
this.nodes = createNodesByHTML(selector);
```

У этого класса куча прототипов которые используют его в том числе изменение стилей и вставка узлов в элемент:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i ++)
                parent.appendChild(this.nodes[i]);
```

после этого действия узлы исчезают из детей `DIV` который мы создали в функции `createNodesByHTML` в следствии этого они пропадают и из `this.nodes` . И дальнейшая работа с экземпляром класса становится невозможно. Приходится искать элементы и потом использовать их. Что делать как поместить детей в переменную `nodes` ?

P.s. Возможно мои суждения и не верны, но другой причины исчезновения узлов из переменной я не вижу, так что если есть другие версии происходящего буду только рад! На всякий случай выкидываю весь скрипт:

```
var w = window, d = document;



(function () {

    var createNodesByHTML = (function(){
        var div = d.createElement("div");
        return function ( html ) {
            div.innerHTML = html;
            return div.children;
        };
    })();

    function  kitNodes  (selector, parent) {
        parent = parent || d;

        if (typeof(selector) == "string") {

            if (selector[0] == "<" && selector [selector.length - 1] == ">" && selector.length >= 7) {
                this.nodes = createNodesByHTML(selector);
            } else {
                this.nodes = parent.querySelectorAll(selector);
            }

        } else if(typeof(selector) == "object"){
            this.nodes = selector;
        }

    }

    kitNodes.prototype.insert = function (parent, index, smooth, callback) {


        if (index >= 0)
            for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++)
                parent.insertBefore(this.nodes[i], parent.children[index + i]);


         else if(position == -1)
            for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i ++)
                parent.appendChild(this.nodes[i]);

        else
            for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i ++)
                parent.insertBefore(this.nodes[i], parent.children[parent.children.length + ++index]);



        if (callback) callback();

        return this;
    };

    kitNodes.prototype.remove = function (smooth, callback) {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i ++)
            this.nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(this.nodes[i]);

        if (callback) callback();

        return this;
    };


    kitNodes.prototype.style = function (styles, smooth, callback) {

        for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i ++){
            var ns = this.nodes[i].style;

            if (styles.width) ns.width = styles.width;
            if (styles.height) ns.height = styles.height;
            if (styles.margin) ns.margin = styles.margin;
            if (styles.padding) ns.padding = styles.padding;
            if (styles.background) ns.background = styles.background;
            if (styles.color) ns.color = styles.color;
            if (styles.lineHeight) ns.lineHeight = styles.lineHeight;
        }

        if (callback) callback();

        return this;
    };

    w.$ = function (selector, parent) {
        return new kitNodes(selector, parent);
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод removeChild возвращает ссылку на удалённый из DOM элемент, попробуйте так:

```
kitNodes.prototype.remove = function (smooth, callback) {
    var node,
        i = 0;

    while(node = this.nodes.item(i)) {
        this.nodes[i] = node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        i++;
    }

    if (callback) callback();

    return this;
};
```